# Can't add worker to Apache Spark

Tags: bigdata, apache-spark

First I started a master locally by command

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
```

It works fine. I can access the web UI through browser in `SPARK_MASTER_IP:8080` from both master and a second machine (the one which I intend to add as a worker).

Then I run the command

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://Williams-MacBook-Air.local:7077
```

( "spark://Williams-MacBook-Air.local:7077" is what I saw in the web UI, and I can use this address to start [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29)/Python shells too.)

Which did not work. Here is what I saw in the console:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
14/07/08 15:59:18 INFO SecurityManager: Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
14/07/08 15:59:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: williamzhang
14/07/08 15:59:18 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(williamzhang)
14/07/08 15:59:19 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
14/07/08 15:59:19 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/07/08 15:59:19 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkWorker@172.25.83.121:55179]
14/07/08 15:59:19 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 172.25.83.121:55179 with 8 cores, 7.0 GB RAM
14/07/08 15:59:19 INFO Worker: Spark home: /Users/williamzhang/spark-1.0.0
14/07/08 15:59:19 INFO WorkerWebUI: Started WorkerWebUI at http://172.25.83.121:8081
14/07/08 15:59:19 INFO Worker: Connecting to master spark://Williams-MacBook-Air.local:7077...
14/07/08 15:59:24 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@Williams-MacBook-Air.local:7077]. Address is now gated for 60000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters.
14/07/08 15:59:24 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef: Message [org.apache.spark.deploy.DeployMessages$RegisterWorker] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/user/Worker#-1453195170] to Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
14/07/08 15:59:39 INFO Worker: Connecting to master spark://Williams-MacBook-Air.local:7077...
14/07/08 15:59:39 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef: Message [org.apache.spark.deploy.DeployMessages$RegisterWorker] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/user/Worker#-1453195170] to Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
14/07/08 15:59:59 INFO Worker: Connecting to master spark://Williams-MacBook-Air.local:7077...
14/07/08 15:59:59 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef: Message [org.apache.spark.deploy.DeployMessages$RegisterWorker] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/user/Worker#-1453195170] to Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
14/07/08 16:00:19 ERROR Worker: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

I also tried:

1. Using the actual IP address rather than what I see in the web UI
2. Restarting the master
3. Using the second machine as master and the first machine as worker

Both machines have Oracle Java 8 64-bits installed. The first one runs [OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) and the second one runs [OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) preview.

Comment: can that master hostname be resolved at the slave? Go to the slave and try `telnet Williams-MacBook-Air.local 7077`   Do you get a connection?

Comment: @maasg Yes, I did get a connection

Answer (score 2):

I hope that it's not too late. Try to run master by the following command: "start-master.sh -h IP_OF_MASTER" and then run slaves. In my case it helped.

Comment: Thanks this helped and I believe the root cause was that in all my configuration (spark-env.sh and spark-defaults.conf) I had used my machine's mDNS name like "MyMachine.local" however my machine had 2 IP addresses - one for WiFi and one for Ethernet. These 2 connections I think confused the spark master binding as well as confusing my worker machines trying to connect. Simply turning off WiFi fixes it. I would suggest as a long term fix to Go into your router and reserve LAN IP addresses for one of your NICs and then use those IP addresses in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the problem, but I think the usual way to add workers is:

```
sbin/start-slave.sh <worker#> <master-spark-URL>
```

At least this works for me. Perhaps the problem with your invocation is that you do not set a worker number.

Comment: This starts a worker, but and the worker can be found in web UI in <worker-ip>:8081, but the master cant see it from <master-ip>:8080.

Comment: Huh. Check the worker logs (in `spark/logs`) to see if you can glean anything from them. Try starting a worker on the master machine to eliminate network as an issue.

Comment: I tried to add master machine as worker and it worked! It turns out that networking is the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I add new worker's hostname to the master file named slaves.
And then, I run the script in master "sbin/start-slaves.sh".

It will show the exists worker is running, the new worker is starting. 
It also will show in the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

To tell Spark to run 4 workers on each slave machine, we'll create a new config file:

```
 # create spark-env.sh file using the provided template:
 cp ./conf/spark-env.sh.template ./conf/spark-env.sh

 # append a configuration param to the end of the file:
 echo "export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4" >> ./conf/spark-env.sh
```

and then start spark as

```
 ./sbin/start-mastet.sh
 ./sbin/start-slaves.sh
```

or

```
 ./start-all.sh
```

result should look like this
[image]

hope this helps
Thanks